# How to reduce the look-and-feel from `sap.m.Button` but keep its functionalities?

Tags: css, sapui5

I am using a [`sap.m.Button`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.Button/sample/sap.m.sample.Button) with an icon to display the status of the users password complexity. The buttons text displays the rule and the icon changes between *accept* and *reject* depending on the rule having been fulfilled.

So I'd like the button not to look like a button. I therefore set its type to `"Transparent"` which removes the borders. Now, only the on hover effect needs to be removed, but how? I tried:

```css
.statusButton .sapMBtnDefault { 
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

but with no effect. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a button but with `sap.ui.core.Icon`, you get the button behavior without the hover effect by default.

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], XMLView => XMLView.create({
  definition: document.getElementById("myxmlview").textContent,
  height: "100%",
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content")));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon_dark"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<script id="myxmlview" type="text/xml">
  <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <App autoFocus="false">
      <Page showHeader="false" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <HBox class="sapUiTinyMargin" alignItems="Center" renderType="Bare">
          <Text id="myText" text="Some password rule" />
          <core:Icon xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
            src="sap-icon://message-success"
            decorative="false"
            size="1.05rem"
            color="Positive"
            class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"
            tooltip="Passed"
            press="alert('You totally clicked a button.')"
          />
        </HBox>
      </Page>
    </App>
  </mvc:View>
</script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

This eliminates the need to create and maintain custom CSS rule, plus, the Icon is highly customizable in terms of color and size out-of-the-box.

**⚠️ Note:** in order to make the icon readable by assistive technologies such as screen readers, set the icon's `decorative` and `noTabStop` properties both to `false`.

[API reference: `sap.ui.core.Icon`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Icon)